# How to add 2 linear gradients background in Tailwind ? static and hover

Tags: css, tailwind-css

`` <Button className={`white-color-text bg-gradient-to-r from-[#f02aa6] to-[#ff6f48] hover:"bg-gradient-to-r from-[#fff] to-[#ff6f48]" bodyS my-4`} text={"Get Started"} /> ``
I cant see to change the background color (which is linear) on active in Tailwind . Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in https://play.tailwindcss.com/?

Comment: my button has this on normal - static : bg-gradient-to-b from-[#4851FF]  to-[#f02aa6] ; i would like to have this on hover :  linear-gradient(
      0deg,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5),
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
    ),
    linear-gradient(180deg, #4851ff -54.32%, #f02aa6 100%);

Comment: I would like a playground from https://play.tailwindcss.com/. It's hard to reproduce this problem with the given code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `hover` modifier with the wrong syntax. Instead of wrapping your `hover` modifier (`hover:"bg-gradient-to-r from-[#fff] to-[#ff6f48]"`), you need to apply the modifier to each segment of your gradient utility:

```html
<div class="bg-gradient-to-r from-[#f02aa6] to-[#ff6f48] hover:bg-gradient-to-r hover:from-[#fff] hover:to-[#ff6f48]">Get Started</div>
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/jqLm0AGFdp)

There's an explanation on how to apply modifiers on each class in the documentation, for example, for the [Gradient Color Stops](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gradient-color-stops#applying-conditionally).

Comment: Also, please note that the class `white-color-text` that you have written should be written this way: `text-white` ([Text Color Utility](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-color))